# how do i retrieve a textbox's title and name using jquery?

Tags: jquery

how do i retrieve a textbox's title and name using jquery?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('#textbox').attr('title')
$('#textbox').attr('name')
```

Answer (score 4):

Textbox, like an input element? Depending on where it is in the document, your selector may vary, but I'll assume you've given it an id, so the HTML would look something like this:

```
<input type="text" title="tehTitle" name="tehName" id="textBox" />
```

Since jQuery selectors use CSS syntax we can [target by `id` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#id-selectors):

```
$("input#textBox") // more to come...
```

You can then use the jQuery [attr function](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to read it's title and name attribute.

```
var title = $("input#textBox").attr("title");
var name = $("input#textBox").attr("name");
```

Answer (score 1):

`var attributeText = $("#textboxID").attr("attributeYouWantToRetrieve");`

just replace title and name for attributeYouWantToRetrieve

Answer (score 0):

```
var theTextBox = $('textarea');
var itsTitle = theTextBox.attr('title');
var itsName = theTextBox.attr('name');
```

Maybe you should do some more tutorials :|

Comment: textbox is not a valid tag, you mean `textarea` i suppose

Comment: @Zlatev: I did indeed... only typed it a few million times before :P